# Advantage of firebase multi-region

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

What are the reasons one would choose firestore multi-region? Is there a performance improvement or just for replication so that data is safe if one region goes down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/locations#location-mr):

> Select a multi-region location to maximize the availability and durability of your database. Multi-region locations can withstand the loss of entire regions and maintain availability without losing data.

So you are paying some extra money to better handle downtime and data safety when thing eventually go wrong for brief moments in time.